# Copy and download files from Sharepoint

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

I am searching since days to find a method how to

1.copy files from a folder (disk) to a sharepoint 
2.copy a file from sharepoint to folder (disk)

My code which I found for question 2 you can find below. But it is not really working. The file is damaged and is only 4kb big after copy.

Does anybody has a solution for me for both questions? MANY MANY THANKS

```
Option Compare Database
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
                                          "URLDownloadToFileA" ( _
                                           ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
                                           ByVal szFileName As String, _
                                           ByVal dwReserved As Long, _
                                           ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Sub DownloadFromSharepoint_DB()

Dim strXls As String
Const strURL As String = "Sharepointlink"

DownloadFileFromSharePoint strURL
strXls = "File"

End Sub

Sub DownloadFileFromSharePoint(strURL As String)

Dim i As Integer
Dim strSavePath As String
Dim returnValue As Long

    strSavePath = "File"
    returnValue = URLDownloadToFile(0, strURL, strSavePath, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I figuered out that the Sharepoint link is permanetly changing when I close the sharepoint and open again.
That means 
e.g. now the Ling is .....1&e=QydH5u
and one sec later it is ..1&e=GtsD2p

unbelievable this software